# Change [quickselect] tag to refer to quickselect algorithm

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The existing tag [quickselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quickselect) should be used for questions regarding jQuery plugin: QuickSelect.

However, when reading  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795433/quick-select-algorithm-vs-heapsort-algorithm), user @JaMiT pointed out that almost every question in this tag is in fact about the [*quickselect* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

I suggest the tag should be redefined accordingly, and a new tag `jquery-quickselect` be defined for the small number of questions really dealing with that plugin.

Comment: I don't see any questions on that tag about jquery - there's two about JS, but both of them are about the algorithm. The tag wiki also explicitly states that the tag is for the algorithm, and not the jquery plugin. I don't really see why this tag is a problem

Comment: @Zoe I did that after seeing the question and forgot posting a comment. Trivial changes like this shouldn't even be brought to Meta.

Comment: In that case, problem solved